# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать iframe адаптивный под все устройства?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Помогите пожалуйста сделать iframe адаптивный под все устройства

Answer (score 1):

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.culture.ru/" width="100%" height="90vh" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="height: 90vh;"></iframe>
```